# Problem displaying multiple robots in Gazebo and RViz

Tags: python, ros, robotics, ros2, gazebo-simu

I use ROS2/Python/Gazebo project. I need to show multiple (in the code below just two) robots. To do it I use the following code snippet:

```
# Define commands for spawing the robots into Gazebo
spawn_robots_cmds = []
for robot in robots:

    robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(urdf)

    params = {
        'robot_description': robot_description_config.toxml(), 
        'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
        #'odom_topic': robot['name'] + '/odom',
    }

    start_robot_state_publisher_cmd = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        condition=IfCondition(use_robot_state_pub),
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher',
        namespace=robot['name'],
        output='screen',
        #tf_prefix=robot['name'],
        # remappings=[
        #     ('/cmd_vel', "/" + robot['name'] + '/cmd_vel'),
        #     ('/odom', "/" + robot['name'] + '/odom')
        # ],
        # remappings=[
        #     ('/tf', '/' + robot['name'] + '/tf'),
        #     ('/tf_static', '/' + robot['name'] + '/tf_static'),
        # ],   
        remappings = [('/tf', 'tf'), ('/tf_static', 'tf_static')],
        parameters=[params]
    )
    spawn_robots_cmds.append(start_robot_state_publisher_cmd)

    params = { 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}
    joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher',
        namespace=robot['name'],
        parameters=[params],
        #condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
        # remappings=[
        #     #('/cmd_vel', "/" + robot['name'] + '/cmd_vel'),
        #     ('/robot_description', "/" + robot['name'] + '/robot_description'),
        #     ('/joint_states', "/" + robot['name'] + '/joint_states'),
        # ],
        #remappings = [('/tf', 'tf'), ('tf_static', 'tf_static')],
    )
    spawn_robots_cmds.append(joint_state_publisher_node)

    spawn_robots_cmds.append(
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(bringup_dir, 'launch',
                                                    'spawn_launch.py')),
            launch_arguments={
                                'x_pose': TextSubstitution(text=str(robot['x_pose'])),
                                'y_pose': TextSubstitution(text=str(robot['y_pose'])),
                                'z_pose': TextSubstitution(text=str(robot['z_pose'])),
                                'robot_name': robot['name'],
                                }.items()))
    
    # spawn_robots_cmds.append(
    #     launch_ros.actions.Node(
    #         package='rviz2',
    #         executable='rviz2',
    #         name='rviz2',
    #         namespace=robot['name'],
    #         arguments=['-d', rviz_config_file],
    #         # remappings=[
    #         #     ("/" + robot['name'] + '/cmd_vel', '/cmd_vel'),
    #         #     ("/" + robot['name'] + '/robot_description', '/robot_description'),
    #         #     ("/" + robot['name'] + '/joint_states', '/joint_states'),
    #         #     ("/" + robot['name'] + '/odom', '/odom')
    #         # ],
    #         output='screen'))
    
    spawn_robots_cmds.append(IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(launch_dir, 'rviz_launch.py')),
        condition=IfCondition(use_rviz),
        launch_arguments={
            'name': robot['name'],
            'namespace': robot['name'],
            'use_namespace': 'True',
            'rviz_config': rviz_config_file}.items()))
```

Then the topic list doesn't contain odom, and robots are not displayed in Gazebo:

```
$ ros2 topic list
/clock
/joint_states
/parameter_events
/performance_metrics
/received_global_plan
/robot1/cmd_vel
/robot1/goal_pose
/robot1/imu
/robot1/initialpose
/robot1/joint_states
/robot1/odom
/robot1/robot_description
/robot1/tf
/robot1/tf_static
/robot2/cmd_vel
/robot2/goal_pose
/robot2/imu
/robot2/initialpose
/robot2/joint_states
/robot2/odom
/robot2/robot_description
/robot2/tf
/robot2/tf_static
/robot_description
/rosout
/tf
/tf_static
```

My robot spawn:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
            arguments=
            [
                '-topic', 'robot_description', 
                '-entity', launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('robot_name'),
                '-robot_namespace', launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('robot_name'),
                '-x', launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('x_pose'),
                '-y', launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('y_pose'),
                '-z', launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('z_pose'),                
            ],
            remappings = [('/tf', 'tf'), ('/tf_static', 'tf_static')],
            output='screen')
    ])
```

Then only one robot moves in Gazebo (as expected), but in both copies of RViz robot "jumps" between two base_links.

How can I teach each copy of RViz to only show its robot?

P.S. I don't mind having two distinct robots in one RViz, but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to prefix all messages and frames with robot's name, then it works. Still, one of the two robots is highlited in RViz, I am not sure why.